# Cakephp validation in light of HTML5

Tags: cakephp-2.3

My question has to do with what appears to be conflicts with HTML5 and Model validation.

I spent close to 4 hours today trying to figure out why my validation function was not working within cakephp only to come to the conclusion that it was because of the browser validation getting in the way.

Once I figured out what was going on I was able to turn off browser validation via the novalidate in the forms opening tag

```
$this->Form->create('Model', array('novalidate' => true));
```

This worked well for turning off the browser validation but it appears to turn off cakephp validation as well because when I submitted the form it went through without stopping. That is unless I set 'required' => true and 'allowEmpty' => false then it stopped it and gave me the error message under the input box like I expected it to. Thing is both of these had to on and set this way for the notEmpty to work.  Problem is it still does not look like other built in functions work at all. For instance I tried to change my credit card validation to cc and it is not stopping the submission of the form.

```
'card_num' => array(
        'rule' => array('cc', 'all', true), // set the $deep to true to check the luhn algorithm
        'message' => 'Invalid CC Number',
        //'allowEmpty' => false,
        //'required' => false,
        //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
        //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
    )
```

Am I missing something that will allow cake to do the model validation and not have the browser validation get in the way? I really liked having cake validation because it is very robust and expandable but it seems to me that all that robustness and expandability is now gone because of browser based validation. What can I do to make both of these work together?

Edit:
I also wanted to expand on my comment about my validation function. I have some fields that are only required if a certain radio button is selected. So I have my own function controlling this and right now the only thing I am doing in the function is return false; So the 3 input fields that are using this function should be putting an error message under my text box but they are not.  That is why I am writing this because it does not appear as though I can set up custom validation of any kind because I have to turn off validation on the form.

Thanks for any help.
Jamie